# How to change drawer header value from another component?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I'm new on react native. I'm using createDrawerNavigator for drawer list in this list i used a component to render a header with logged in user name. But i want to change that name from another component( profile screen). I'm unable to find solution.

Here is my drawer navigator code :

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="home" size={20} color="#0f1f7b" />
        )
    },
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Profile',
      drawerIcon: () => (
        <Icon name="user" size={20} color="#0f1f7b" />
      ),
    },
  },
  Logout: {
    screen: Logout,
    navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Logout',
        drawerIcon: () => (
          <Icon name="sign-out" size={20} color="#0f1f7b" />
          )
    },
  }
},
{
  drawerBackgroundColor: "#fff",
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#000',
    inactiveTintColor: '#000',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#bfc7f3',
    itemStyle: {
      fontSize: 12,
    },
  },
  contentComponent: (props) => (
            <View>
              <ScrollView>
              <DrawerUserDetail />

                <DrawerItems
                  {...props}
                  getLabel = {(scene) => (
                    <View style={{width:width/1.9}}>
                      <Text style={{color:'#000',fontSize:18,fontWeight:'500',paddingBottom:10,paddingTop:10}}>{props.getLabel(scene)}</Text>
                    </View>
                  )}
                />
                </ScrollView>
              </View>
            )
});
```

Here is drawer user detail code :

```
constructor(props){
    super()
    this.state={
      name:'',
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.profileBg}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'#fff',fontWeight:'600',left:20}}>Hello! {this.state.name}</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
```

I want change name state from profile component whenever user update name it will reflect on drawer screen.

Comment: This is a great example use case to show the importance of redux, like it is mentioned on the Redux way solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446030/react-redux-access-state-from-other-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate component and use this component in your DrawerNavigator.

```
<DrawerUserDetail  navigation={props.navigation} />
```

And here is component :

```
export default class DrawerUserDetail extends Component<Props> {

componentDidMount() {
  //You can call your API here.
}

<View style={styles.profileBg}>
        <View style={styles.profileHeader}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{this.state.name}{' '}</Text>
          <Text onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileUpdate')}
           style={styles.changePassword}>Manage Account</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
}
```